# Making responses to public nodes only viewable by the creator and the originator

Tags: views, nodes, 6, entities, comments

I've got a prototype site built in D6, pertinent modules:

- CCK
- Comment block
- Node Comment
- Views
- Views Or

The site is built around a list of open requests; to solicit a private response. These nodes are of content type Request.

All open requests are public in that all users (logged in or not) can view these nodes.

When a response (comment) is received to an open request it should only be viewed by the author of the original request, or the author of the response.

These responses should be shown to these users on the original node as comments and on a seperate list.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick search on D.o. came up with this forum post asking to do the exact same thing: http://drupal.org/node/919914

They suggest using Node Comment and [Content Access](http://drupal.org/project/content_access) together to achieve it, but I'm not certain Content Access will give you the specific option you're looking for.

It would be a start though, and you might be able to hook into Content Access and create a new "Parent Node author" or similar option if you are up for a coding session.

Comment: I'm always up for coding; but often with Drupal there is a better way of doing things than simply writing code. Writing code where I should have been using modules was my first mistake.

Comment: I do get that, but hooking into modules to extend functionality or simply modifying code to provide new functionality as a patch is also the Drupal way :)